# Windows 11 Snipping tool doesn't have Paint 3D option like Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, screenshot, snipping-tool

In Windows 10, when you use the Snipping Tool, there's a button that is the Paint 3D icon.  If you press it, it'll open what you just snipped in Paint 3D.  This allows you to do far more than what's available in the Snipping Tool.

Here's an image of what I'm talking about:
[image: Snipping Tool Windows 10 option to open snip in Paint 3D]

In Windows 11 Snipping Tool, that option seems to be gone, ruining my image-taking workflow.

Am I missing something?  Is there a way, in Windows 11, to:

- use Snipping Tool to take a image
- open than image in Paint 3D (or some native drawing program)

EDIT: yes, I could save the screenshot (sigh), open Paint 3D (another sigh), navigate to the saved screenshot, and open it there.

That's a LOT of time wasted.  Like, too much.  The beauty of Paint 3D being accessible in the Snipping Tool program was that I could take a screenshot and in single keystroke be able to edit it on Paint.

If I were to do all those steps above, I'd use a nicer screenshotting program.

Comment: After you snip the image save it somewhere, then open Paint and drag the image file into Paint.

Comment: @Moab that is WAY too many keystrokes.  The entire point of Snipping Tool to Paint 3D is that is was quick.

Comment: You said it, it does not have that feature and no way to add it. What you can try is copy the exe for the snip tool from a W10 machine and see if it will run in W11

Comment: @Moab great idea!

Comment: Let us know if it works please. @Bob